# FeynRules issue when trying to export UFO file

Tags: export, physics, python

I am having problems with the UFO file generated by a very simple model using [FeynRules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_calculation_of_particle_interaction_or_decay#Feynman_rules_generators). The following error occurs when [MadGraph](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1405.0301) tries to import the "Model_UFO" file:

```
MG5_aMC> import model Model_UFO
Command "import model Model_UFO" interrupted with error:
SyntaxError : can't assign to literal (lorentz.py, line 11)
```

The origin of the error is traced to line 11 of the lorentz.py which reads

```
1 = Lorentz(name = '1',
            spins = [],
            structure = '1')
```

I am not very familiar with Python, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Why is FeynRule treating "1" as a variable?

Comment: This StackExchange site is for the software Wolfram Mathematica. Are you sure that you are at the right place to ask your question?

Comment: @halirutan googling Feynrules the first hit says "FeynRules is a Mathematica® package that allows the calculation of Feynman rules in momentum space for any QFT physics model."

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries [I'm still not convinced](https://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/wiki/PythonInterface) since he pastes python code, but I might be wrong.

Comment: It is a Mathematica package. All the calculations are done in Mathematica then extracted into a set of files (UFO) in Python code that can be used for other stuff (e.g. MadGraph). It is true that the problem I am having lies just in the Mathematica/Python Interface.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's a bug in *FeynRules* that results in generating incorrect Python code. But, I've never used this package, and I suppose a majority of other users of this site will be in the same situation. You might be better off to contact the authors of the package.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Ok , will do that.